# how to create 2 level admin users in django where each user will administer only the users he creates?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I need to create more than 1 admin user who can administer roles/permissions to only the users he creates in django.This admin should be able to see only the users he creates and not the users created by another user. In short I wish to use the django as a SaaS model for my customers, where he can administer his employees/users only.Is this possible and how exactly can this be implemented? Eg. Admin A can create users for his company A and set roles for them, Admin B can create users for his company B and set their roles. But at the same time Admin A should not be able to see users created by admin B and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You aren't going to want to use the Django admin panel for this though. You should be writing custom "admin" areas for these users.

Comment: @SamCreamer can you broadly show how the user class will be defined for that purpose?

Comment: Just a suggestion here, maybe you should think of this problem more generic, like multi-tenancy. Then each company can have multiple admins but they will have access to users for only their company. In this case, link the User model to a Company model, and then in the admin page filter out users based on the admin's company.

Comment: @GabrielMuj exactly this way, but the admin of 1 company should not be able to see the users of another company when he logs in admin panel

Answer (score 6):

Step-1. django-admin startproject twoadminproject

Step-2. `cd twoadminproject`

Step-3. `python manage.py startapp twoadminapp`

Step-4. Change models.py of "twoadminapp" app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

Step-5. Change settings.py:

```
# Add you app in INSTALLED_APPS list

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'twoadminapp',
]

# Add one line at the end

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'twoadminapp.User'
```

Step-6. `python manage.py makemigrations`

Step-7. `python manage.py migrate`

Step-8. `python manage.py createsuperuser` (Execute this command twice for creating two admin users)

Step-9. Change admin.py of "twoadminapp" app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User

# Register your models here.


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        users = super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return users.filter(created_by=request.user.username)


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

So, whenever you add user from admin panel, you have to fill admin username in the created by field of 'add user form' or you can initialize it in forms.py

Comment: This definitely creates 2 admin users. But I want to create a hierarchy of users each administering the users he  creates. Users created by others is not visible to his peer.

Comment: You should change `created_by` to a `ForeignKey`-relation to `self` for working with the `User` rather than the username (e.g. what if you swap usernames?). Next you still need to override/implement the `UserAdmin.has_change_permission()` to check if the user was created by the currently viewing one. Otherwise you can change other users by simply rewriting the url.